# Scatter plot for multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I'm trying to plot the following data in Excel using a scatter plot

```
Income     1960   1961   1962   1963   1964   1965
Algeria    1280   1085    855   1128   1170   1215
Argentina  5251   5448   5316   4956   5375   5855
Bahamas   11926  12558  13186  13858  14584  15374
```

The data is the GDP per capita in USD.

I want to make a scatter plot that shows the year on the x axis and the GDP on the y axis. But I want to do this for all the countries in my table.

How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming your data starts in cell `A1` and ends in cell `G4` without any gaps, if you select `A1` and then insert a new Scatter Chart, Excel will create the chart you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you've tried, but it seems just selecting the data, going to Scatter Chart, does the trick:

[image]

Comment: I think its because there were gaps in my origional data it did not work hmm